# PhoneGap Facebook plugin Init() function

Tags: javascript, android, facebook, cordova, init

Do I have to call the FB.Init() function every time I load a page?

I'm using PhoneGap, I call facebook init() to initialize the ID app in the index.html, but when I move to another html page, each time I call any other facebook function it appears this:

> FB.getLoginStatus() called before calling FB.init()

So, is there any way/method to call this function only once?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I finally did was to store the information provided by FB.login() method in LocalStore like:

```
localStorage.setItem("token", response.authResponse.accessToken);
```

and then to get the info:

```
localStorage.getItem("token");
```

So there's no need to get the status again when moving to other html pages.